# Image to din a4 pdf with imagemagick

Tags: pdf, image-processing, imagemagick

I have different images some are small and some of them are very large. I want to convert the images to a pdf.

By now I have a working command:

```
convert.exe -page A4 test.png xc:white -gravity center -composite -format pdf -resize "595x842>" test.pdf
```

The problem is, that if I use this the quality of the images is quite bad. If I open an imageviewer and print with a installed pdf-printer like bullzip, the image is clear and sharp in the pdf. Using convert, the quality is low and I can see the pixels on 100%.

I want to center the image, resized if they are larger than din a4, the image should be resized proportionally and the result should be always in din a4.
I have tried different setups, but once the image is sharp enough, the size of the pdf is not din a4 or the pagesize is correct, but only an edge of the image is visible.

Does anyone have a working command? Maybe with an explanation why?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way. Make two test images, one big and red, one small and blue both with contrasting borders so we can see the edges:

```
convert -size 800x900 gradient:black-red -bordercolor yellow -border 5 big.png
```

[image]

```
convert -size 400x600 gradient:black-blue -bordercolor magenta -border 5 small.png
```

[image]

Now we should, hopefully (!) be able to make them into PDFs with:

```
convert small.png -resize "595x842>" -gravity center -extent 595x842 testsmall.pdf

convert big.png -resize "595x842>" -gravity center -extent 595x842 testbig.pdf
```

I also did some experiments using Ghostscript directly - but it seems that Ghostscript can't read PNG files nor can it centre images - I think. I am happy to be shown I am wrong if anyone knows better. So, I looked for an intermediate file format in which ImageMagick can centre a high-quality image and which Ghostscript can then make into PDF. I came up with EPS3 and tried this:

```
convert  big.png -resize 2480x3508 -gravity center -extent 2480x3508 eps3:temp.eps
```

(Replace `eps3:temp.eps` with `temp.png` to check it is centred as you wish)

Then

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=result.pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dEPSFitPage temp.eps
```

Not sure if that works for you?

Comment: Thanks, it seems the problem stays the same. I made two screenshots both of them are zoomed 400%. This one is from convert: https://i.imgur.com/wVEeB0E.png and this image is created with a pdf-printer https://i.imgur.com/lYIrKB4.png. The image was originally taken by smartphone cam. The quality of the pdf-printer is way better than the pdf created by convert.

Comment: with this command-line the quality of the image is way better, "
convert.exe test3.jpg -resize "1000x2000>"  -background white -extent 1000x2000 -page A4 start.pdf" but the image is not centered, adding "gravity -center" resutls in having a complete white page. Any further ideas?

Comment: thanks, with the conversion from convert and afterwards pushin it to ghostscript it works and the quality is way better than imagemagick alone.

Comment: With both imagemagic and gs this solution allows also to change the dpi for the image, Thanks